# Update html page values with PHP

Tags: php, html, http, request, response

I would like to update html page several times during my PHP script execution.
I understand, that when I requested something like http://index.php the index.php script will return html page in response.
I have my index.php code like:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(120);
$_SESSION['my_number'] = 0;
//header('Refresh:2 url=http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head/>
<body>
<p style="color:blue;">my_number is <?php echo $_SESSION['my_number']; ?> </p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
foreach (array(1,2,3,4) as $v) {
    $_SESSION['my_number'] = $v;
    sleep(10);
}
?>
```

It displays only `my_number is 0`

If I move `foreach` before html body - it display `my_number is 4`.

But I would like to get the html page with the updating `my_number` every 10 seconds.
So the number should be overwriteen every 10 seconds.

I tried to add

`header('Refresh:2 url=http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` but still no luck.

Somehow I need to send several responses to browser before exiting the php script. Fist response to load page, others - to update my_number values.

I prefer to get solution only within php. Not using javascript if possible.

Comment: To change something on the page after page is loaded - use __javascript__. No exceptions.

Comment: @u_mulder `a:hover`? 

Comment: Exception: `a:hover` )

Comment: I dont understand. Did you try _GET or _POST?

Comment: I tried _POST instead of _SESSION - same result, no update for html page